# link working on localhost, not on live

Tags: html

I do not understand why my link "back to portfolio" is working on my localhost, and not on my live domain. The only links there is not working, is the back to portfolio button.

Can anybody see why?

[My portfolio link](http://vouzalis.com/berries.php)

```
<span class="col-xs-12">
  <a href="portfolio.php" class="btn btn-border">
     <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
        Back to Portfolio
   /a>
   <a href="contact.php" class="btn btn-border">
      <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>
         Work with me?
   </a>
</span>
```

Comment: `Portfolio.php` vs. `portfolio.php` - You'll notice accessing the first is a 404, which is where your link goes in your live version, but accessing the latter is successful.

Comment: Also, please close the `</a>` tag correctly

Comment: This question is off-topic because it relies on an external link to view and understand the problem. When writing questions, please ensure everything readers need to see is in the question itself. Links may be placed at the end, but only if the question would be answerable without them (such as fiddles and pasteboards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span class="col-xs-12">
  <a href="Portfolio.php" class="btn btn-border">
     <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
        Back to Portfolio
   /a>
   <a href="contact.php" class="btn btn-border">
      <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>
         Work with me?
   </a>
</span>
```

its case sensitive change fine name o Portfolio or vise versa

Comment: Argh shoot. I think I am seeing myself tired on it. Time to stop :) Thank you for your answer. I can first accept it in 10 minutes... Stack overflow says.